# I suddenly failed to install Express in node.js with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I suddenly failed to install Express with node.js in Typescript. Here is the warning:

[image]

I initialized the npm, started the index.js. tsconfig.json, installed ts-node. My command for ts-node and Express is as follows:

```
npm install ts-node typescript @types/node
npm install express @types/express
```

Desperately looking for your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shown in the picture is caused by missing permissions. Just put a `sudo` ahead.

```
sudo npm install -g ts-node
```

to install typescript globally enter the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```

Comment: Just curious, but why did I suddenly encounter such a problem?